# How to make listview more efective?

Tags: android, android-listview

From old google  [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) I remember we should never use android:layout_height = "wrap_content" is it still true? 
Which of the following layout is better?
Autogenerated implementation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Limited to availible height

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Surrounded by another layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `wrap_content` because that would make the `ListView` calculate its full height, and that would involve go throughout all list items initialise them and get the views itself so its still true that you should never ever use `wrap_content`.

In the third option you surround it in a `LinearLayout` which is useless because so the `ListView` can be moved upper to the parent and so saving one level in the view hierarchy as such:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

The second version achieves the same as this version im giving, however it uses `layout_weight` the difference actually on using the version i post here and the second actually depends on what you're trying to accomplish, the version i post will make the `ListView` height be exactly equal to the parent while the second version will distribute the remaining height between any the `ListView` and any other views you place inside the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

It is still applicable, and it's preferable to have the `ListView` and its `parents` have either `match_parent` or `height=0 and a weight`, in your case 2nd and 3rd are good

Comment: Is there any reason to use 3rd case? I saw few examples with it, but don know it it give any benefits

Comment: I don't see any reason why not, I personally did that more than once

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use first case. When you use "weight" parameter your device spend a lot of resources to calculate it. Use Views without "weight" in case when your try to save performance.

Comment: it is highly unrecommended to use wrap_content for a listview's height